# Set preference value in unity, Not able to get in android

Tags: android, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I set preference value in unity using below code

```
rightJointPos = rightJoint.localPosition;
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("rigX", rightJointPos.x);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("rigY", rightJointPos.y);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("rigZ", rightJointPos.z);

        PlayerPrefs.Save ();
```

And I fetch value in android using below code..

```
SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        float rigX=settings.getFloat("rigX", 0.0f);
        float rigY=settings.getFloat("rigY", 0.0f);
        float rigZ=settings.getFloat("rigZ", 0.0f);



        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"start   11   "+rigX+ ":"+rigY+":"+rigZ, 400).show();
```

I print this value in toast..always i got 0.0 value not actual value..

How can I get this value in android?
please help me to solve this..what is missing in this code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey did you try the answer I left? Did it work?

Comment: I tried but did not get value

Answer (score 2):

Android's `SharedPreferences` and Unity's `PlayerPrefs` are totally different data storage API with different implementation, and both are not interchangeable.

If you save with `PlayerPrefs.SetFloat`, you must read with `PlayerPrefs.GetFloat`

```
float rigX = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("rigX", 0.0f);
float rigY = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("rigY", 0.0f);
float rigZ = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("rigZ", 0.0f);
```

If you are making this call from Java  and you need to read the `PlayerPrefs`, you have to use `UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage` to get those `PlayerPrefs` values. Since `UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage` cannot return a value, you need a wrapper on top of it.

**C#**:

```
class SettingsReader : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Sends the data from PlayerPrefs to the receiveResult function in Java
    void sendResultToJava(float value)
    {
        AndroidJavaClass javaPlugin = new  AndroidJavaClass("com.company.product.MyPlugin");
        javaPlugin.Call("receiveResult", new object[] { value.ToString() } );
    }

    //Called from Java to get the saved PlayerPrefs
    void getValue(string key)
    {
        float value = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(key) //Get the saved value from key
        sendResultToJava(value); //Send the value to Java
    }
}
```

**Java**:

Package: *com.company.product.MyPlugin*

```
public final class MyPlugin
{
    string result = "";

    //Gets saved value 
    float getSavedValue(string key)
    {
        //Calls Unity function "getValue" from a script attached to GameObject named GameObjectName then pass in the key
        UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("GameObjectName", "getValue", key);
        return Float.parseFloat(result); 
    }

    //Receives result from C# and saves it to result  variable
    void receiveResult(string value)
    {
        result = "";//Clear old data
        result = value; //Get new one
    }
}
```

Usage from Java side:

```
float rigX = getSavedValue("rigX");
float rigY = getSavedValue("rigY");
float rigZ = getSavedValue("rigZ");
```